# How would Quantum Phase Estimation be solved classically?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-phase-estimation

I would be interested to know how Quantum Phase Estimation (QPE) would be solved classically. So suppose we have a matrix and a vector description of $U$ and $|\psi\rangle$.

I would present here what I myself would understand by a classical solution of this problem. I would be very interested to know if this represents already a "classical QPE".

Approach:

Let $U = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}$ and the input vector $|\psi\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{2}+1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

The eigenvalue problem is defined as:

$U|\psi\rangle = \lambda |\psi\rangle$

I now insert the components that are given and thus determine the eigenvalue $\lambda$

$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{2}+1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \lambda \begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{2}+1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{2}-1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}= \lambda \begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{2}+1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{2}-1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}= (-1) \begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{2}+1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Since $-1 = e^{2\pi i (1/2)}$ it follows $\phi = 1/2$

Can this be called a classical solution of the QPE, or are there other methods that are typically called classical here?

Comment: Are you asking how to find the eigenvalue corresponding to a given matrix and eigenvector?

Comment: Basically I am only interested in how one would solve QPE classically. So yes :) (I have tried to show what I (for myself) understand by a classical solution above. But I am not sure if this is a classical solution.)

Comment: solving the (classical) problem of finding the eigenvalue corresonding to a given matrix and eigenvector (under the promise that the given vector is indeed an eigenvector) really isn't hard. But I don't know that it's fair to compare that to QPE. For one thing, in QPE you don't need to have a description of the state $|\psi\rangle$ for the protocol to work. Also, for larger numbers of qubits, you wouldn't even be able to store the vector corresponding to the state (unless some assumption on sparsity is made), so it's not obvious how to even define such "classical problem" in that case

Comment: @gIS feel free to make your comment into an answer, then I would be happy to accept this as an answer. You (or via reference) might want to elaborate on why a description of the state $|\psi\rangle$ is not needed for the protocol to work.

Comment: I also agree that @gIS's answer is solid :) and just to answer your final question,  I can give you a black-box of the operator $U$ and the state $|\psi\rangle$ without telling you what they are explicitly, you can still perform QPE to tell me what the eigenvalue is. E.g. if I tell you that $U=e^{i2\pi\theta}|\psi\rangle$, then proceed to give you the black-boxes $U$ and $U^{\dagger}$ and the starting state $|\psi\rangle$, you can create a circuit to perform QPE to find $\theta$ without knowing any details about $|\psi\rangle$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving the (classical) problem of finding the eigenvalue corresponding to a given matrix and eigenvector (under the promise that the given vector is indeed an eigenvector) really isn't hard. But I don't know that it's fair to compare that to QPE. For one thing, in QPE you don't need to have a description of the state $|ψ⟩$ for the protocol to work.

Also, for larger numbers of qubits, you wouldn't even be able to store the vector corresponding to the state (unless some assumption on sparsity is made), so it's not obvious how to even define such "classical problem" in that case.

*(converted from a comment)*